# Cloud Functions for Firebase database onWrite triggered twice after request is removed

Tags: node.js, function, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a friend request function which is fired when a request is sent,   but if the user rejects the request the `onWrite` is fired again. 
    How can i return the promise if the request node in firebase db is removed.

```
exports.sendFreindRequestNotification = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
    let friendRequest = event.data.current.val();
    let senderUid = friendRequest.requests;
    let receiverUid = friendRequest.uid;
    let promises = [];

    for (key in senderUid) {
        console.log('my Key', key);
    }

    //Some kind of logic to return the the promise if the friend request value is removed from firebase db to avoid firing again.
    if (receiverUid == key) {
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }

    let getInstanceIdPromise =  admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiverUid}/pushToken`).once('value'); 
    let getSenderUidPromise = admin.auth().getUser(key);

    return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getSenderUidPromise]).then(results => {
        let instanceId = results[0].val();
        let sender = results[1];
        console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + friendRequest.displayName + ' from ' + key);
        console.log('Sender ', sender);

        let payload = {
            notification: {
                body: 'You have a new friend request from ' + sender.email,
                sound: 'default'
            },
            'data': { 
                'notificationType': "friendRequest" 
          }
        };

        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please try to post the minimum amount of code that you need to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only want Cloud Functions to fire when the request is created. You can do that by registering for `onCreate`:

```
exports.sendFreindRequestNotification = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}')
.onCreate(event => {
```

For more information see the [documentation on setting event handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler).